# Compare two column Pandas row per row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare 2 column. If same will True if not same will False like this:

| filtering | lemmatization | check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [hello, world] | [hello, world] | True |
| [grape, durian] | [apple, grape] | False |

The output from my code is all False. But, the data actually is different. Why?

You can get my data [github](https://github.com/jovanap17/Sentiment-Analysis)

```
import pandas as pd

dc = pd.read_excel('./data clean (spaCy).xlsx')
dc['check'] = dc['filtering'].equals(dc['lemmatization'])
```

Comment: Note that [`pd.Series.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.equals.html) does a row-wise comparison but return one Boolean for the full Series, not one per row, see in the doc in the return *"True if all elements are the same in both objects, False otherwise."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is difference between columns - in one column missing `''` around strings, possible solution is convert both columns to lists, for comapre use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (working like `==`):

```
import ast

dc = pd.read_excel('data clean (spaCy).xlsx')

#removed trailing [] and split by ` ,`
dc['filtering'] = dc['filtering'].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ')
#there are string separators, so working literal_eval
dc['lemmatization'] = dc['lemmatization'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

#compare
dc['check'] = dc['filtering'].eq(dc['lemmatization'])
print (dc.head())
   label                                          filtering  \
0      2                                         [ppkm, ya]   
1      2  [mohon, informasi, pgs, pasar, turi, ppkm, buk...   
2      2                                      [rumah, ppkm]   
3      1  [pangkal, penanganan, pandemi, indonesia, terk...   
4      1                              [ppkm, mikro, anjing]   

                                       lemmatization  check  
0                                         [ppkm, ya]   True  
1  [mohon, informasi, pgs, pasar, turi, ppkm, buk...   True  
2                                      [rumah, ppkm]   True  
3  [pangkal, tangan, pandemi, indonesia, kesan, s...  False  
4                              [ppkm, mikro, anjing]   True
```

Reason for `False` is [`Series.equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.equals.html) return scalar, so here `False`

Comment: I tried this code too and have same output.